# Oracle: Select on data from a CSV file

Tags: oracle

I have a CSV file with many integers in the form:

```
id
---
1
2
3
```

I need to write a statement that selects ids from a table that are in the list in my CSV.

I could just convert the data 1000 elements at a time into a SQL IN like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (....)
```

but that would take hundreds of queries, is there a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an [Oracle External Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm).

First, create a directory pointing at the directory holding the .csv file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY MYDIRECTORY AS '/path/to/yourdirectory';
```

Grant read access to your user:

```
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY MYDIRECTORY TO YOURUSER;
```

Create a table that'll read from your CSV file:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  id NUMBER
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY MYDIRECTORY 
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
      (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS (id NUMBER)
      )
    LOCATION ('yourfile.csv')
 );
```

Your query would then be:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT id FROM MYTABLE);
```